# Have Android devices centralised AGPS service?

Tags: android, geolocation

Have all Android devices centralised AGPS/triangulation service they use to detect coarse (network based) location? Or has do manufacturer of Android devices maintain their own AGPS services for their own devices?

Answer (score 0):

This second is correct: "has do manufacturer of Android devices maintain their own AGPS services for their own devices"